# Read duplicate or repetitive columns from csv and append them into common columns -Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
I have a csv file that look like this.

MONTHS  A     B      C       MONTHS   A       B       C
0   15024   15700   27795       0   22536   23550   41692
1   12415   15700   23001       1   18623   23550   34501
2   10620   15700   19434       2   15930   23550   29151
3   9304    15700   16696       3   13957   23550   25045
4   8296    15700   14542       4   12444   23550   21813
```

What I am looking is append the common columns, which would look like this.

```
 MONTHS A         B       C     D
    0   15024   15700   27795   1
    1   12415   15700   23001   1
    2   10620   15700   19434   1
    3   9304    15700   16696   1
    4   8296    15700   14542   1
    0   22536   23550   41692   2
    1   18623   23550   34501   2
    2   15930   23550   29151   2
    3   13957   23550   25045   2
    4   12444   23550   21813   2
```

The Last column D just denotes the order in which it occurred. The long way is to read specific columns and then somehow reshape the columns. Is there an easy way around it?

Comment: Don't post images. Post actual data instead. Check - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csvfile = StringIO("""MONTHS  A     B      C       MONTHS   A       B       C
0   15024   15700   27795       0   22536   23550   41692
1   12415   15700   23001       1   18623   23550   34501
2   10620   15700   19434       2   15930   23550   29151
3   9304    15700   16696       3   13957   23550   25045
4   8296    15700   14542       4   12444   23550   21813""")


df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
df_out = df.stack(1).rename_axis(['Month', 'D']).reset_index()
df_out['D'] = df_out['D'].fillna(0).astype(int).add(1)
df_out = df_out.sort_values(['D','Month'])
df_out
```

Output:

```
   Month  D      A      B      C  MONTHS
0      0  1  15024  15700  27795       0
2      1  1  12415  15700  23001       1
4      2  1  10620  15700  19434       2
6      3  1   9304  15700  16696       3
8      4  1   8296  15700  14542       4
1      0  2  22536  23550  41692       0
3      1  2  18623  23550  34501       1
5      2  2  15930  23550  29151       2
7      3  2  13957  23550  25045       3
9      4  2  12444  23550  21813       4
```